# Redshift Row_number() different numbers on different runs

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

In the top level of a select statement I have a row_number select that looks like this:

```
    Row_number() over (
        PARTITION BY
        field1, field2
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC NULLS LAST
    ) as ts_rank
```

I've been noticing inconsistent behavior with this query.
If I re-execute look at the `ts_rank` column somtimes it will contain 4 1s and 3 2s or 5 1s and 2 2s or 6 1s and 1 2... etc

I understand that, if my partitions include similar values (they don't in this case) ordering is not guaranteed to be the same.

But it makes no sense that the amount of `rank 1` and `rank 2` rows should vary...

Is there a potential bug in redshift that might be causing this ? Or some sort of inconsistencies I'm not considering ?

Comment: what is your data? are the timestamps identical?

Comment: No they are no, but, even under the assumption that they were, this kind of undeterminism makes no sense

Comment: As in, assuming 2 identical timestamp 2 rows can have rank 1 and 2 intechangably, but the "amount" of ranks 1 and rank 2 are the exact same

Comment: I'm trying to generate a smaller table and see if I can replicate this right nwo

Comment: yes - i see what you mean - can you add some data to your question that will replicate the issue? failing that try aws support?

Comment: do you use `limit` in your query?

Comment: I did not, no..

Comment: I have the same issue. When through SQLWorkbench it works. But when running through shell I get funny results

Answer (score 0):

So, I've long since given up on working on the project where this was involved.

A guy from our company who was in contact with AWS asked them about it, but as far as I know no workaround was given and no fix was implemented.

The way I went around it is by just modifying my queries not to use `Row_number`, so the solution here is just to not use the functionality, accept the indeterminism or, if you're in a position where you can, switch to a good column-store database (e.g. mariadb column store or clickhouse)